# Javascript filter - returning by id's

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, filter

I have a js object, the array has 25 entries.

```
 {             
   id:1,
   title: 'item1'
},
{             
   id:2,
   title: 'item2'
},
{             
   id:3,
   title: 'item3'
},

{             
   id:4,
   title: 'item4'
},

{             
   id:5,
   title: 'item5'
},
```

I am trying to return 3 items out of the 25 but make it random.

I filter my object and filter them by id.

```
  return this.talents.filter(
          function (talent) {  
            return talent.id === 3
          });
```

What I really want to do is return 3 from an array.  So I tried this without any luck

```
$.each([ 1, 2 ], function( index, value ) {     
    return this.talents.filter(
      function (talent) {  
        return talent.id === value
      });
});
```

How can I filter/select a JS object by a value like this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, could you maybe supply some input and your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
var values = [1, 2];

return this.talents.filter(function(talent) {
    return values.some(function(val) { return talent.id === val });
})
```

Example:

```js
var values = [1, 2];
var talents = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 }
];

var filteredTalents = talents.filter(function(talent) {
  return values.some(function(val) {
    return talent.id === val
  });
});

console.log(filteredTalents);
```